# Single word for "Expanding and Contracting"

Tags: single-word-requests

Specifically expanding and contracting without the connotation of rhythm that comes with pulsate. Oscillate, librate, undulate might all be synonyms but lack association with expanding and contracting.

e.g. There is a theory that the universe ______.

Fluctuates (but specifically for expanding/contracting).

Comment: *Fluctuates in size* would surely do. And you might get away with something like *throbs*, although that may warrant a bit of explanation. "There is a theory that the universe throbs, expanding and contracting erratically over a period of billennia" or something.

Comment: @Andrew_Leach Still looking for a single word... It would seem throbs has the same rhythmic connotation as pulsate. But, fluctuate in size certainly pins down the concept I'm looking for, Much appreciated :).

Comment: I would suggest "pulsating".

Comment: Why do people insist on single terms for words that are the opposite of each other?

Comment: Generally people insist on single terms for words that are the opposite of each other because they're programming and want a short variable name for something that controls changes in two directions, e.g. you tell the software to "expand or contract" by setting this parameter to different values. This is strictly speaking off-topic, owing to a ban on asking for variable names, but they try and get around it.

Comment: @Lambie  for the same reason one would use the term “rotation” to describe both a left and a right rotation.  It’s simply a generalization to include both actions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change you sentence slightly, which would give you the flexibility to use lots of different words:

> There is a theory that the size of the universe is _____.

Especially with words like *oscillate*, you have to tell us **what** is oscillating.  There are a few words like *pendulate* that are more specific about what's going on, but *oscillate* only tells you that something is changing magnitude, not what is changing magnitude.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I feel like your "oscillate" works best here especially with the direct reference to physics. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Cyclic Model of the universe proposes an ongoing cycle of expansion, then contraction, then repeat. 
This is also called the Oscillating Universe theory.

[This definition nicely captures the reason:](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:oscillating)

> Oscillate 2. [Physics] - Vary in magnitude or position in a regular manner
>   around a central point.

Answer (score 0):

How about the word “dilates”.  It’s usually used to refer to pupils increasing but also decreasing in size to adjust to light.   I don’t like the words pulsate or oscillate because both imply going back and forth in a regular fashion which is not what you are asking for.

Comment: Hello, B flat. While I agree that what you say in the last sentence is true, I feel that your suggestion, using an unusual sense of 'dilate', also isn't ideal. I think OP (Hangman) is probably best sticking with 'fluctuates' if they don't want to use more words. (Though they've probably forgotten their question by now.)

Comment: Oh wow.  I didn’t notice the date.  Dilate has a geometrical meaning in mathematics which means to expand or contract in size.  https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/dilation.html

Comment: I’m using dilate to collectively refer to both positive and negative divergence (contraction and expansion) in a 2 and 3 dimensional vector fields.

Comment: But wasn't Hangman looking for a word most people would understand more easily?

Answer (score -2):

Balloons.

Both expansion and contraction are indicated by the physics of a balloon. It's simple and everyone can relate. Win win.

KT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The definition is not what you say it is. From NOAD, the definition of balloon (verb): "swell out in a spherical shape; billow: *the trousers ballooned out below his waist*".